# How to edit SEBLOD content?

Tags: joomla-3.4, seblod

Trying to help a friend with a website that uses SEBLOD.  We can find the relevant article, but it only shows:

```
::cck::4::/cck::
```

I can see in the database with phpmyadmin where the content is stored, under joomla_cck_store_form_apartments.  But I cannot find where that would be available for editing in the admin end of the website.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: I believe clicking the item in the article manager will open the seblod form based on its content type. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks, Turns out that the website was just broken And wasn't bringing up the proper form.  Only the regular article template was loading, not the seblod override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening **Components > SEBLOD 3.x** and start looking under **Forms & Content Types** first.

Good luck